# How to verify no null elements in list, Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, null

I'd like to check a `List<Int?>` for nulls and if no nulls exist, then allow the List to proceed as a `List<Int>`, otherwise use an `emptyList()`

This is what I came up with:

```
var noNullElements: List<Int> = emptyList()
if (listWithPossibleNullElements.all { it != null }) {
    noNullElements = listWithPossibleNullElements as List<Int>
}
//do something with noNullElements list
```

I'd be shocked if this was the best, most idiomatic way.

**Solution**

There are many acceptable solutions below, but the one I chose was a combination of the solutions

```
fun getSafeList(list: List<Int?>): List<Int> =if (null in list) emptyList() else list.requireNoNulls()
```

Comment: `if (null in list) emptyList() else list.requireNoNulls()` is short, has no warnings, and doesn’t do a list copy.

Comment: @Tenfour04 would this throw exception?

Comment: Only if the underlying List is actually mutable and some other thread is adding null values to the list while this code is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a one liner [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions):

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> Iterable<T?>.filterNoneNull(): Iterable<T>? =
  takeIf { null !in it }?.requireNoNulls()
```

- [`takeIf {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#takeif-and-takeunless) - a scope function that will return null if the lambda evaluates to false
- `null !in it` - use the [`in` operator function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#in-operator) to determine if the list contains `null`
- finally, if `takeIf {}` returns a non-null value, [`filterNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) will convert the element type from the nullable `T?` to non-null `T`

Note that it will return `null` if the provided `Iterable<T?>` contains `null`, else `List<T>`, in case it's important to differentiate between the provided list being empty, or containing `null`. An alternative can be provided using the [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).

Example usage - [*run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/_rAEqmjar):

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val listA: List<Int?> = listOf(1, 2, 3, null)

  // since listA contains 'null', the result is 'null'
  println(listA.filterNoneNull())
  // prints: null

  // provide an alternative, using the elvis operator
  println(listA.filterNoneNull() ?: emptyList<Int>())
  // prints: []

  val listB: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3)

  // since listB does not contain null, the same list is returned
  println(listB.filterNoneNull())
  // prints: [1, 2, 3]
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> Iterable<T?>.filterNoneNull(): Iterable<T>? =
  takeIf { null !in it }?.requireNoNulls()
```

---

Note: I edited the question and replaced [`filterNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) with [`requireNoNulls()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/require-no-nulls.html), as the latter will not instantiate a new list

Comment: This looks very interesting, it seems to do exactly what I want.  Let me test it.

Answer (score 2):

Check with [contains](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-elements.html#check-element-existence) for the existence of at least one *null* value:

```
val noNullElements = if (list.contains(null)) emptyList() else list.map { it!! }
```

Edit: Added this extension function:

```
fun List<Int?>.castToIntOrEmpty() = 
  if (this.contains(null)) emptyList() else this.map { it as Int }

val noNullElements = list.castToIntOrEmpty()
```

Example with no *null* elements:

```
val list: List<Int?> = List(10) { it }
// list is: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

val noNullElements = if (list.contains(null)) emptyList() else list.map { it!! }

println(noNullElements)   // Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Example with some (or all) *null* elements:

```
val list: List<Int?> = List(10) { if (it % 2 == 0) it else null }
// list is: [0, null, 2, null, 4, null, 6, null, 8, null]

val nullElements = if (list.contains(null)) emptyList() else list.map { it!! }

println(nullElements)   // Output: []
```

Comment: I added some more details to my question.  The key point being that I want to change the type from List<Int?> to List<Int>.  The contains function is promising although

Comment: You could add _.requireNoNulls()_ to _list_ in the _else_ clause, or use _list.map { it!! }_.

Comment: I edited my answer an added _.map { it!! }_ to _list_.

Comment: [`list.filterNotNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) is more idiomatic than `list.map { it!! }`.

Comment: @aSemy I think _.map { it!! }_ makes it more clear that we know the _list_ to not contain any _null_ at that moment.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is you want to take a generic `List<Int?>` type and treat it as a `List<Int>`, which means casting it. Because `List<Int?>` isn't a subtype of `List<Int>` (although the inverse is true, as *Joffrey* points out in the comments) you basically have to perform an unchecked cast in this situation:

```
if (list.contains(null)) emptyList else list as List<Int>
```

The compiler isn't smart enough to determine that this is a safe cast at runtime (and you have to be able to make that guarantee yourself, e.g. ensuring the list isn't being modified elsewhere to include a null after the check passes) so you'll get an *unchecked cast* warning. [The documentation on generics goes into your options](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#unchecked-casts), but if you really want to pass in a `List<Int?>` and treat it as a `List<Int>`, you'll have to suppress that warning:

> An unchecked cast warning can be suppressed by annotating the statement or the declaration where it occurs with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`

---

I'd argue the more *idiomatic* approach is to just create a new `List<Int>` instead of trying to cast the original one to a different generic type, or to make the original list provider pass a `List<Int>?` instead (i.e. *null* if there were any non-null elements) which is maybe just moving the problem - but it really depends on what you're doing.

You can easily create filtered copies and compare it to the original to decide whether to use it, or write a `for` loop building a new list that short-circuits if you hit a null, all those kinds of things. If you want to check first and only copy if you need it, [lukas.j's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932458/13598222) has more examples (including a couple that throw exceptions, like `requireNoNulls()`) so you have a lot of options, and there are different tradeoffs - it really depends on what you're doing and where the bottlenecks are (if any). Things can get a bit awkward when you work with generics, so some situations don't end up looking as neat as you'd like!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do.  I couldn't find a good way without the "UNCHECKED_CAST".  Thank you for adding facts to my presumptions.

Comment: In Kotlin, `List` is covariant, so yes, `List<Int>` *is* in fact a subtype of `List<Int?>` ([example](https://pl.kotl.in/1YlbtXKZT)). That said, generic type erasure still exists, and the cast is still unchecked in Kotlin, so that doesn't invalidate your point, but the answer should be edited to fix the misleading part.

Comment: @Joffrey oh you're right, I was in the Java mindset when I wrote that bit for some reason - I'll edit it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`filterNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html):

```
val noNullElements: List<Int> = listWithPossibleNullElements.filterNotNull()
```

Comment: The question is not about filtering. As far as I understand the question, the OP wants an empty list if the list contains any _null_.